# Is there a team meta like in League of Legends for Conquest mode?

Tags: smite

I come from League of Legends, there most of the games, but not necessarily all, are composed by:

- Top lane: Bruiser / Tank
- Jungle: Tankish...
- Mid lane: Mage
- Bottom lane: Physical Damage Carry
- Bottom lane: Support

Usually something like that.

And now I want to understand if there is any meta on Smite, is there some team composition that is recommended to follow? How should we pick our team? Do we have/need a full support?  Are there junglers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **typical team composition** is:

- **Two players** in the **long lane** (left or right), with an ADC (all damage carry; physical ranged) and a support (typically building tank, hand of the gods, and warding; often rotating for mid-camps).
- **Mid lane** a **Mage**.
- **Solo lane** (short side lane) with a solo-capable god; often a bruiser.
- One player as a **jungler**.

In lower level play a jungler is not always present. In higher (mid to high) level play a **jungler is present** because it **distributes xp and gold better between teammates** (the additional gold and xp from the jungle as well as the solo laner not having to split with another player in lane).

The **typical players distribution at the start of a game** depends on whether the long lane is left or right.

If the **long lane** is **left**, the duo goes for their sides blue buff, while the other three players go for the right mid-harpies. The mid player then goes for mid, while the jungler and solo laner go for red and blue buff, then into the solo lane. The jungler takes the red, the solo the blue buff.

If the **long lane** is **right**, the jungler helps left solo to get his blue buff. The other three players take the right mid-harpies, mid goes mid afterwards, and duo takes their sides blue - which the ADC takes.

At around 1:40 the support may rotate to the mid-harpies to catch them at 2:00 with his HoG.

The **jungler** (may) initially helps out the solo laner (otherwise he could get pushed back hard two on one by the enemy jungler supporting his solo). The jungler mainly clears his jungle, and ganks whoever seems gank-able by over-extension or vulnerable god - situational anyway.